# How caching declaration is done for LoadingCache

Tags: java, spring, caching, guava, google-guava-cache

Can I connect `LoadingCache` with a `@Cacheable` method.

I need GuavaCache to support refreshAfterWrite

```
return new GuavaCache("cacheName", CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .maximumSize(maxSize)
                .expireAfterWrite(expireAfterWriteInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .ticker(ticker)
                .build());
```

to

```
return CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .maximumSize(maxSize)
                .refreshAfterWrite(refreshAfterWriteInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build(
                        new CacheLoader<Integer, List<Type>>() {
                            @Override
                            public  List<Type> load(Integer id) {
                                return service.getServiceItem(id);
                            }
                        }
                );
    }
```

but I don't understand how to connect this `LoadingCache` with a Spring Cache declaration `@Cacheable("cacheName")`

Comment: [This tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-caching-abstraction-and) may help you integrate the Guava cache with Spring's caching abstraction. This should be possible with a [`CacheManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/CacheManager.html)

Comment: yes but I specifically need to use LoadingCache, not GuavaCache